# No shadows inside UIStackView

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, calayer, uistackview

I have a peculiar problem that I'm not sure why it happens. I was trying to add shadows to a normal view which I accomplished easily. However when embedding these views in a stackview, I got some bizzare results:

Normal Shadows:

[image]

Stack View Shadows:

[image]

As you can see, this is quite wrong, and I'm not sure why this happens. My code is simple and is as follows:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var stackYellowBox: UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var stackBlueBox: UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var yellowBox: UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var blueBox: UIView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()            
        setupStackShadows()
        setupNormalShadows()
    }

    private func setupStackShadows() {
        stackYellowBox.layer.masksToBounds = false
        stackYellowBox.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
        stackYellowBox.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.5
        stackYellowBox.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 10, height: 10)
        stackYellowBox.layer.shadowRadius = 1
        stackYellowBox.layer.shadowPath = UIBezierPath(rect: stackYellowBox.bounds).cgPath
        stackYellowBox.layer.shouldRasterize = true
        stackYellowBox.layer.rasterizationScale = UIScreen.main.scale

        stackBlueBox.layer.masksToBounds = false
        stackBlueBox.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
        stackBlueBox.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.5
        stackBlueBox.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 10, height: 10)
        stackBlueBox.layer.shadowRadius = 1
        stackBlueBox.layer.shadowPath = UIBezierPath(rect: stackBlueBox.bounds).cgPath
        stackBlueBox.layer.shouldRasterize = true
        stackBlueBox.layer.rasterizationScale = UIScreen.main.scale
    }

    private func setupNormalShadows() {
        yellowBox.layer.masksToBounds = false
        yellowBox.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
        yellowBox.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.5
        yellowBox.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 10, height: 10)
        yellowBox.layer.shadowRadius = 1
        yellowBox.layer.shadowPath = UIBezierPath(rect: yellowBox.bounds).cgPath
        yellowBox.layer.shouldRasterize = true
        yellowBox.layer.rasterizationScale = UIScreen.main.scale

        blueBox.layer.masksToBounds = false
        blueBox.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
        blueBox.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.5
        blueBox.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 10, height: 10)
        blueBox.layer.shadowRadius = 1
        blueBox.layer.shadowPath = UIBezierPath(rect: blueBox.bounds).cgPath
        blueBox.layer.shouldRasterize = true
        blueBox.layer.rasterizationScale = UIScreen.main.scale
    }


}
```

Any help with this issue is highly appreciated. This issues seems very strange to me. Thank you

**EDIT**

The following contraints may be of use:

[image]

Comment: Its too early to call `setupStackShadows()`. Move after viewDidLayoutSubviews()

Comment: You mean like this? `override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() { super.viewDidLayoutSubviews(); setupStackShadows() }`. Still get the same results

Comment: Your code works fine in my demo project. Do you set the right `@IBOutlet` binding between your view and Storyboard?

Comment: Yes, I have. Could it be the constraints? I have a feeling the stack view is not big enough to hold the shadows (since it hugs the views) and some strange warping occurs on the shadows. However, I'm not sure how to allow contingency for shadows actually (stack view is made to hug the views in it right?)

Comment: Instead of repeating code, use extension in Swift to set shadows. That would make your code look nicer.

Comment: Sure. This was just for demonstration. I have a nib loaded and connected though IBInspectable for this. Didn't want to paste all that here.

Comment: I'm seeing similar behaviour. Did you solve this?